# PlantUML does not render arrows well in a class diagram (Skinparam linetype ortho mode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, class-diagram, orthogonal, plantuml

I'm trying to make some complex class diagrams with PlantUML by having ortho layout for the relations between the classes.

Some arrows, especially those which are connected at the bottom of an element does not rendered very well.

If it is important, I use VS Code with jebbs.plantuml extension.

Anybody with the same experience?

[image: Arrows are not rendered well in class diagram by using Skinparam linetype ortho mode]

Comment: Can you show the, plantuml, code that you used for this diagram, maybe even try it on http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml (the plantuml webserver). Which version of plantuml are you using?

Comment: Hey @albert, 
Thanks a lot for the response. I checked my code on plantuml.com/plantuml/uml and the result was great.
Maybe I have some old version of the render on my machine.

I'll try to follow the instructions and install the latest version of all dependencies including Graphviz and I'll try to use my environment (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml) again.

I'll get back to you once again with the results.
You already gave me a great hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem looks like to be due to an old version of plantuml. The newest released version can be found through the plantuml main page http://plantuml.com/ on http://plantuml.com/download.

The latest available plantuml.jar beta file: http://beta.plantuml.net/plantuml.jar (at http://beta.plantuml.net/ you might also find other files of the latest beta version)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with installing the latest version of Plantuml.jar as well as latest version (2.38) of Graphviz.
It looks like I used the older one (2.28)

Thank you for the help.